# T-SQL select rows where [col] = MIN([col])

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a data set produced from a `UNION` query that aggregates data from 2 sources.

I want to select that data based on whether or not data was found in only of those sources,or both.

The data relevant parts of the set looks like this, there are a number of other columns:

| row | preference | group | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 111 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 111 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 135 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 135 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 135 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 | 111 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 135 | 1 |

The `[preference]` column combined with the `[group]` column is what I'm trying to filter on, I want to return all the rows that have the same `[preference]` as the `MIN([preference])` for each `[group]`

The desired output given the data above would be rows 1 -> 6

The `[preference]` column indicates the original source of the data in the `UNION` query so a legitimate data set could look like:

| row | preference | group | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 111 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 111 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 111 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 135 | 1 |

In which case the desired output would be rows 1,2,3, & 5

What I can't work out is how to do (not real code):

`SELECT * WHERE [preference] = MIN([preference]) PARTITION BY [group]`

Comment: Did you try to use a subquery like `SELECT [group], min(preference) AS minPref FROM... GROUP BY [group]` and then simply perform an inner join to this subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using `RANK`:

```
SELECT row
  , preference
  , [group]
  , position
FROM (  
   SELECT row
     , preference
     , [group]
     , position
     , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY preference) AS seq
   FROM t) t2
WHERE seq = 1
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb4a54/4)

Comment: I ended up using `DENSE_RANK()` but essentially this got me to the solution I needed. I knew there would be something I just was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Should by doable via simple inner join:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM t AS t1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT [group], MIN(preference) AS preference
                FROM t
                GROUP BY [group]
              ) t2 ON t1.[group] = t2.[group]
                   AND t1.preference = t2.preference
```

Comment: This would work in normal circumstances, but unfortunate my data set isn't a table, its actually a sub-query inside a much bigger query and is reliant on the `OUTPUT` from a previous `INSERT` - in a nutshell it was complicated.